# Access m:properties in XML object in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML object in my javascript code. Now I would like to get the content of the `<d:Attachment>` tag and store in a separate variable. How do I do this?

```xml
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
       xml:base="https://fioriq.gerdau.com:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZVS_GLNSCNF_GW_SRV/">
  <id>…</id>
  <title type="text">Text Title</title>
  <updated>2017-05-31T19:09:36Z</updated>
  <category term="ZVS_GLNSCNF_GW_SRV.Form"
            scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme">
  </category>
  <link href="FormSet(Scnfid='1',Formid='1')" rel="self" title="Form"></link>
  <content type="image/jpeg" src="FormSet(Scnfid='1',Formid='1')/$value"></content>
  <m:properties>
    <d:Attachment></d:Attachment>
    <d:Imagebase64></d:Imagebase64>
    <d:MimeType>image/jpeg</d:MimeType>
    <d:Scnfid>1</d:Scnfid>
    <d:Formid>1</d:Formid>
    <d:Description></d:Description>
    <d:Owner></d:Owner>
   <d:Attachmentid>1</d:Attachmentid>
  </m:properties>
</entry>
```

This is my object

`var xmlStr = jQuery.parseXML(oEvent.getParameters().files[0].responseRaw);`

I have tried this
`var attachment = xmlStr.getElementsByTagName("Attachment");`

and this
`var attachment = xmlStr.getElementsByTagName("d\\:Attachment");`

None of this works.
The second way returns an HTMLCollection object. But I just want the content of this tag

---

### Update

This way works for iOS devices:

```js
var attachment = xmlStr.getElementsByTagName("d:Attachment")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

This way works for Android devices:

```js
var items = xmlStr.getElementsByTagName("Attachment");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var attachment = items[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS?

Comment: If you want to post code or markup, please [edit] your question

Comment: Just edited my question